# Equivalents of Farpoint KeyAscii and UnFmtText in Dot net Masked control?

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have migrated Vb6 control to Vb.Net and I replaced farpoint input pro mask text box to Dot Net masked test box. .

Here, I am replacing KeyPress event of Far Point with Dot Net Maksed control, But I am not able to find any alternative for e.KeyAscii and mskRealSSN.UnFmtText in Dot net Masked control. Please help me on this.

```
Private Sub mskRealSSN_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles mskRealSSN.KeyPress
    If  e.KeyAscii = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Return Then
        RaiseEvent RealSSNEntered(Me, New  RealSSNEnteredEventArgs(mskRealSSN.UnFmtText))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: EDIT: What did UnFmtText do in VB6?

Comment: its farpoint masked control property and i dont know what it does.

Comment: It's going to be hard to find an alternative for something you don't know what it does. What's going on in function `RealSSNEntered`? Do you have the code to that?

Comment: looks like UnFmtText  is an un format text and  alternative property would be text in Dot Net Masked control.

Comment: @hardcode do you know what would be the alternative for KeyAscii?

Comment: `If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Return) Then (...)`